# Django checkbox display content

Tags: django, checkbox, fedora-commons

I try to display different content.
But something i make false. 
If i check pid it must show only pid's, if i check pid and title it must show both.
In my example i show both, but how i can change it with checkboxes?
Thanks.

```
<form class="fedora" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    <input type="checkbox"  name="pid" value="{{obj.pid}}"> pid
    <input type="checkbox" checked name="title" value="{{obj.title}}"> title
</form>

...

{% fedora_access %}
        <p><a href="{% url 'display' obj.pid %}"> 
        {%if  obj.pid %} {{ obj.pid }}|{% endif %}          
        {{ obj.pid }} | {{ obj.title }}  
        </a></p>  
{% end_fedora_access %}
```

Comment: You can do it using jquery alone. Wrap `{{obj.title}}` in a span, and on checkbox click, just show or hide the title

Answer (score 1):

```
<form class="fedora" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    <input type="checkbox" id="show_pid"  name="pid" value="{{obj.pid}}"> pid
    <input type="checkbox" id="show_title" checked name="title" value="{{obj.title}}"> title
</form>

...

{% fedora_access %}
        <p><a href="{% url 'display' obj.pid %}">      
        <span class="show_pid">{{ obj.pid }}</span> | <span class="show_title">{{ obj.title }}</span>
        </a></p>  
{% end_fedora_access %}
```

Then in javascript:

```
$(function() {
    $('#show_pid').click(function() {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) $('.show_pid').show();
        else                        $('.show_pid').hide();
    });
    $('#show_title').click(function() {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) $('.show_title').show();
        else                        $('.show_title').hide();
    });
});
```

although, when neither are checked, you'll have `|` still showing. You can fake that with css. Give the spans a `border-left: 1px solid black` and a `border-right: 1px solid black` or something.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I want to make it without javascript. Just using form

Comment: <form class="fedora" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }} <input class="suche_fedora" type="submit" value="SEARCH"/>
  <input type="checkbox" id="show_pid"  name="pid" value="{{obj.pid}}"> pid
  <input type="checkbox" id="show_title" name="title" value="{{obj.title}}"> title
</form>